# How to remove src folder from npm package when it is published?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, package, publish

I have this library published on npm: https://github.com/felire/react-native-animated-dots-carousel

But I would like to avoid npm to publish the src folder, I also don't know if it is a good idea. How much things can I remove from publish? I would like the package size be the less possible when is used by npm.

And how can I test how the package would look like after publish?

Or maybe the size from those unnecessary folders are too short that I shouldn't worry about that. What do you think?

Thanks!

I tried to google the answer but I haven't found too much, and I really don't want to make a mistake publishing it since it is a library that is being used and it is active.

I think my "files" from package.json is absolutely wrong, but as I said, I don't want to make a mistake when I republish it

```
 "files": [
    "src",
    "lib",
    "android",
    "ios",
    "cpp",
    "react-native-animated-dots-carousel.podspec",
    "!lib/typescript/example",
    "!**/__tests__",
    "!**/__fixtures__",
    "!**/__mocks__"
  ],
```

Comment: If you don't want to include src in the package why is it listed in files?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `src` from the array of `files` :

```
 "files": [
    "lib",
    "android",
    "ios",
    "cpp",
    "react-native-animated-dots-carousel.podspec",
    "!lib/typescript/example",
    "!**/__tests__",
    "!**/__fixtures__",
    "!**/__mocks__"
  ],
```